# cannot write a list of integers, which were made strings to a text file

Tags: python, list, filehandle

Hi I'm opening and closing an input and an output file as "infile" and "outfile" and using them in a command line argument to extract specific content from one file to another. However the infile content is a list of integers and as I now know I have to turn them to strings to complete the task...

```
for lines in infile:
    words=lines.split("\t")
    wated=words[15]
    if wated == "559292":
        dataA.append(str(words[1]))#attempt to write list of integers as strings to file
    outfile.write(dataA+'n')#'+n' apparently needed for this process.
```

However I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError:can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

When I try it without the "+'n'":

```
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Comment: First error is exactly what the error message says; you can't add a list and a string. Second error message: `write` takes a string; you're passing it a list.

Comment: Maybe `dataA` is a list?

Answer (score 0):

Change to this, if you want to store that list in a file:

```
....
outfile.write(str(dataA)+'n')#'+n' apparently needed for this process.
....
```

Comment: This will technically work but I don't think it's what he really wants because for an input file of N lines, you're outputting a list with 0-to-N elements, N times, for a total of O(N^2). The output file will be a couple megabytes large if the input file is around a kilobyte.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you only want each `words[1]` value to appear in the output file once, in which case you can do one of these:

- don't bother with a list; just write `words[1]` directly to the file
- wait until the end of the loop before writing the list to the file

Your current approach seems to be a mix of the above choices, which is no good. I also assume that when you add "n", you are actually trying to add a newline.

```
for lines in infile:
  words=lines.split("\t")
  wated=words[15]
  if wated == "559292":
    outfile.write(str(words[1])+'\n')
```

Or

```
for lines in infile:
  words=lines.split("\t")
  wated=words[15]
  if wated == "559292":
    dataA.append(str(words[1])+'\n')
outfile.writelines(dataA)
```